# Segmentation fault when assigning string pointer via stringstream::str() in c++

Tags: c++11, stringstream

I'd like to assign std::string *ptr via stringstream::str() in C++.
I have a class below.

```
class A{
public:
    A():ptr(nullptr){
    }
    void read(string& filename){ // this file contains a text. 
          std::ifstream ifs(filename);
          std::stringstream ss;
          ss << ifs;
          *ptr=ss.str();
          ifs.close();
    }
private:
    std::string *ptr;
};

int main(void){
    A a();
    std::string file="./file";
    a.read(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that "*ptr" can be assigned by the text.
However, segmentation fault occurs at *ptr=ss.str().
How can I do that?
I think appending temporal object is one way to go as below.

```
//instead of *ptr=ss.str();
std::string str=ss.str(); 
ptr = &str;
```

But I dont want to create temporal object.
Thanks

Comment: You're dereferencing unitialized pointer. That is the problem.

Comment: Actually I have created such ctor omitting here. Even if I initialize ptr by nullptr, segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your `ptr` to being able to dereference it. (and not to `nullptr`, which cannot de dereferenced obviously)

```cpp
A() {
  ptr = new std::string();
}
~A() {
  delete ptr;
}
```

---

*Also, assigning temporal variable is not a way to go, because after leaving the scope you will have garbage in your pointer*